# Swift json decoder with mixed array

Tags: swift, jsondecoder

Looking for help to decode irregular (for a lack of a better word) json. As an example:

```
[
    {
        "texts":
        [
            {
                "value": "value 1"
            }
        ],
    
        "commentType": "someComment"
    },
    
    {
        "texts":
        [
            {
                "value": "value 2"
            }
        ],
        "commentType": "someComment2"
    },
    
    {
        "texts":
        [
            {
                "evidences": 
                [
                    {
                        "evidenceCode": "code 1",
                    },
                    {
                        "evidenceCode": "code 2",
                    },
                    {
                        "evidenceCode": "code 3",
                    },
                    {
                        "evidenceCode": "code 4",
                    }
                ],
                
                "value": "value 3"
            }
        ],
        "commentType": "someComment3"
    }
]
```

I can decode `comment` and the first two "texts":

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case texts
    case commentType
}

do {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .commentType)
    
    if let texts = try container.decodeIfPresent([[String: String]].self, forKey: .texts) {
        for text in texts {
            if let value = text["value"] {
                // add to model object
            }
        }
    }

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

But I get an error for the third "texts" block:

> "Expected to decode String but found an array instead."

Which I understand, since now instead of an array of `[String:String]`, it is a mixed array of `[String:[String:String]` and `[String:String]`.

How do I decode `value3` from that third block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is not complicated at all because the content of `texts` is the same if we treat `evidences` as an optional array. The below models will decode the json correctly without any custom code.

```
struct Result: Decodable {
    var texts: [TextData]
    var commentType: String
}

struct TextData: Decodable {
    let evidences: [Evidence]?
    let value: String
}

struct Evidence: Decodable {
    let evidenceCode: String
}
```